# How to calculate the error in measurments of derived quantities knowing the error in basic quantities?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I wonder how to calculate error of a derived  quantity $z$ knowing the error of all quantities that $z$ depends on say $x$ and $y$.

For example:

> Suppose I want to calculate the speed of a body knowing that the distance is $10$ meters with error $0.5$ meter and in a time $2$ seconds in an error $0.1$ second.
>
> How can I calculate the error of the speed?

Is the way is to calculate the highest and lowest speed of the body in the domain of error ($10.5/4.9$ and $9.5/5.1$ )and then calculate the error  as follows: the error is the difference between any of those extreme values (lowest or highest) and the average of them?

Am I getting it right? Or Is there any way to calculate the error?

Comment: This is called [error propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider some measurments $x$ and $y$. Say there is some derived quantity $z$ which depends on $x$ and $y$ with some function $z=f(x,y)$, the error on $z$ is $\sigma_z$ and is given by $$\sigma_z=\left[ \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2 \sigma^2_x + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)^2 \sigma^2_y\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$
where $\sigma_x$ is the error on the x variable and dito for the y variable.
This extends generally to functions with lots of variables, just keep adding terms inside the square braces similar to the form of the ones shown.

So for your specific example you have $v=\frac{x}{t}$ so
$$\sigma_v=\left[ \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right)^2 \sigma^2_x + \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \right)^2 \sigma^2_t\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\left[ \left( \frac{1}{t}\right)^2 \sigma^2_x + \left(\frac{x}{t^2} \right)^2 \sigma^2_t\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$

If you actually put the numbers in and work this out it may give you a slightly different answer compared to finding the maximum and minium values and then halving the difference. This is due to the above expression only being to first order in a Taylor expansion, propagation of errors can become quite tricky so we stop here most of the time as the above formula is good enough in most cases.

Comment: Ok thank you, but What values does $t$ and $x$ take? in my example?

Comment: $x$ would be 10m and $t$ would be 2s.

Comment: Oh, I see now, they should be the real values I got through measurment.

Answer (score 0):

I do it different way, but it winds up with the same answer as Chris.
For products or quotients, I add The percent errors in quadrature.
That gives $\sigma_v=[(\sigma_x/x)^2+(\sigma_t/t)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}(x/t)$ in your case.

Comment: This is just a simple case of the general result above. Your formula comes from the result above. The results for products and sums are generally just "known" as they are quite common